# Most efficient way for partially drawing an UIView in drawRect:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, core-graphics

I'm using `setNeedsDisplayInRect:` as much as possible in my UIView subclass, but I don't know what to do in `drawRect:`. What is the best way to detect which parts of the UIView have to be drawn? Right now I've divided my UIView into several `CGRect`'s. For each `CGRect` I'm calling `CGRectContainsRect()` to check whether that `CGRect` needs to be drawn or not. Is that the correct way, or is there a better way?

Comment: Sounds like you're wanting to tile things, have you looked at using a CATiledLayer instead? Let it do the tiling for you, and just draw on the layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at a classic spatial partitioning task.  Depending on your view complexity, you can use different strategies to find out what needs to be drawn.  If your scene is very simple, then drawing everything or partitioning the scene into discrete areas and doing your bounding rectangle check is fine.  For very complex scenes, there are several good data structures (such as octrees) for representing your scene as a tree, and performing spacial queries for objects within a given region.

Check out the topic of Spacial Partitioning on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_partitioning

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to draw any rect that is even partially in the invalidated rect, so you'll want to use `CGRectIntersectsRect()`.  Having said that, I've seen few cases where it makes sense to partially draw UIViews -- unless you have a very large single view inside of a scroll view, you may as well draw the whole thing.